# Get time to press a key in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, time

```
if (a == 1) {
        cout << "Press a" << endl;
        Sleep(500); // I tried to do it this way but it didn't work
        if(GetKeyState('A') & 0x80000){
            cout << "Nice" << endl;
    }}
```

I don't have enough time to press a key, maybe you have any solutions.

Comment: If you're going to keep everything in a single thread like this, I'd strongly suggest switching to a [State Machine Design](https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/state-machine-design-in-c/184401236).

Comment: `GetKeyState` reflects the keyboard state the last time a message was processed, and your loop isn't processing any messages. Try `GetAsyncKeyState` instead. Note that you would have to be holding the key down at the exact time the function is called for it to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JonathanPotter has pointed out a solution.

The following is an example code working for me. You can have a try to see if it helps.

[`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) and `GetKeyState` return `SHORT`, so compare the return value with `0x8000` instead of `0x80000`.

```
DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunc(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x41) & 0x8000) {
            cout << "Nice" << endl;
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    HANDLE threadHdl = CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (threadHdl == NULL)
    {
        DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
        cout << "CreateThread fails with error: " << errCode;
        return FALSE;
    }

    cout << "Press a" << endl;

    WaitForSingleObject(threadHdl, INFINITE);
}
```

Comment: The return value of `GetLastError` is meaningless at the point you are calling it.